# meteor unknown package (0.9.0)

Tags: meteor, meteorite

I just updated my meteor application to meteor version 0.9.0

All seems to work well. The problem however now is that when I do a fresh checkout of my project and try to run it I get errors like this:

```
% meteor
Figuring out the best package versions to use. This may take a moment.
Could not resolve the specified constraints for this project:
Error: unknown package: subs-manager
```

So I tried to install the packages as follows:

```
% meteor add subs-manager
Figuring out the best package versions to use. This may take a moment.
Could not resolve the specified constraints for this project:
Error: unknown package: subs-manager
```

and next I tried:

```
% mrt install subs-manager

Done installing smart packages
```

But when I try to run `meteor` again I get the exact same error message. Any suggestions what goes wrong here ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to migrate your package names:

```
meteor remove subs-manager
meteor add meteorhacks:subs-manager
```

You can check out the names by searching atmosphere, which I think uses the new naming system now or using `meteor search` e.g `meteor search subsmanager`